# When i run this code, i cant get leg number, instead i got "<class '__main__.animal'>". But i should get 4. What is the reason. What should i do?

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

```
class animal():
    def __init__(self,leg_number=4,cell_number="multicellular",feeding="grass"):
        self.leg_number= leg_number
        self.cell_number= cell_number
        self.feeding= feeding
class dog(animal):

    def __init__(self,leg_number=4,cell_number="multicellular",feeding="meat"):
        super().__init__(leg_number,cell_number)
        self.feeding= feeding
        print( "this dog has  leg number: {}\ncell type: {}\nfeeding type {}".format(self.leg_number,self.cell_number,self.feeding))

a = dog(animal)
```

When i run this code, i cant get leg number, instead i got "". But i should get 4. What is the reason. What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't pass `animal` to `dog` when you are creating and instance just do a = dog(). dog inherits from animal, that doesn't mean you should pass it. Only pass things you want to pass to your constructor (i.e. to the `__init__`).

What your code was doing was printing the class object itself: `print(animal)`.

So:

```
class animal():
    def __init__(self,leg_number=4,cell_number="multicellular",feeding="grass"):
        self.leg_number= leg_number
        self.cell_number= cell_number
        self.feeding= feeding
class dog(animal):

    def __init__(self,leg_number=4,cell_number="multicellular",feeding="meat"):
        super().__init__(leg_number,cell_number)
        self.feeding= feeding
        print( "this dog has  leg number: {}\ncell type: {}\nfeeding type {}".format(self.leg_number,self.cell_number,self.feeding))

a = dog()
```

Though I would recommend a cleaner approach:

```
class animal():
    def __init__(self, leg_number ,cell_number, feeding):
        self.leg_number = leg_number
        self.cell_number = cell_number
        self.feeding = feeding
    def __str__(self):
        return f"This {self.__class__.__name__} has {self.leg_number} legs, {self.cell_number} cell type, and feeds on {self.feeding}."
class dog(animal):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(4, "multicellular", "meat")
    def bark(self):
        print("Woof")

a = dog()
print(a)
a.bark()
```

Output:

```
This dog has 4 legs, multicellular cell type, and feeds on meat.
Woof
```

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!. Now it works. Thank you very much :) How did i do this mistake hehe:) I am just in learning phase in python. Thank you.

Comment: @CanerErdoğan Don't forget to mark it as an answer. Also take a look at my recommended version at the bottom. Inheritance can be extremely powerful and leveraged a lot better than what you are currently experimenting with.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert but you are formatting the leg_number for output.

The Animal has 4 legs, but the dog is being set with a leg number of "asd", did you mean to do that?

Comment: Just after i posted my response, the op edited the question. it did say self,leg_number="asd",cell_number="multicellular"